# Hiding dropdown with jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a Sharepoint site I need to hide a dropdown list that appears on the ribbon, the following code does not throw any error but the dropdown is not hidden, I also tried .hide

A screenshot:
http://screencast.com/t/c8JXLH03

My code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("span#Ribbon.Tabs.InfoPathListTab.Views.ddViews-Medium").css('display', 'none');
});
```

The html generated of that elemnt.

```
<span class="ms-cui-dd" id="Ribbon.Tabs.InfoPathListTab.Views.ddViews-Medium" unselectable="on" mscui:controltype="DropDown"><span class="ms-cui-dd-text" style="width: 100px" unselectable="on"><a>Nuevo</a></span><a class="ms-cui-dd-arrow-button" id="Ribbon.Tabs.InfoPathListTab.Views.ddViews" unselectable="on" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" aria-haspopup="true" aria-describedby="Ribbon.Tabs.InfoPathListTab.Views.ddViews_ToolTip"><span class=" ms-cui-img-5by3 ms-cui-img-cont-float ms-cui-imageDisabled" unselectable="on"><img class="" style="top: -35px;left: -27px;" unselectable="on" src="/_layouts/15/3082/images/formatmap16x16.png?rev=23"></span><label class="ms-cui-hidden" unselectable="on">Vistas</label></a></span>
```

Comment: I think the problem is related to how jquery parses the selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.` characters in the `id` need to be escaped so that they are not interpreted as a `class` selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Ribbon\\.Tabs\\.InfoPathListTab\\.Views\\.ddViews-Medium").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use an attribute selector rather than escaping the `.` characters.

```
$('span[id="Ribbon.Tabs.InfoPathListTab.Views.ddViews-Medium"]').hide();
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/udy0nxho/)